# If statements not working on the second run round a loop of functions

Tags: python, tkinter

i have a function(player1grid) for creating an array of buttons displayed on a tkinter canvas, the buttons are almost the same (placed in different places) and use the same function(buttonpress) when pressed, however they need to have different values that are sent to buttonpress when clicked. buttonpress then does a few things, calls a couple other functions that eventually lead back to player1grid to create a turn based game. I use the loop and the list (buttonspressed1) to check if the button in that space as already been clicked in which case it wont place another button there so the player cant click the same one twice.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import Tkinter as tk
    from Tkinter import *
else:
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *

from PIL import ImageTk, Image
def play():
    A1= ['00','20','10']

    A2= ['00','20','10']
    def hit(player):
        if player == "1":
            print("player 1 hit")
        else:
            print("player 2 hit")

    def miss(x,y,player):
        if player == "1":
            print("player 1 miss")
        else:
            print("player 2 miss")
            
    def buttonpress(val,player,grid,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2):
        checkforhit = False
        if player == "1":
            if val in A1:
                A1.remove(val)
                checkforhit = True
            elif val in C1:
                C1.remove(val)
                checkforhit = True
            elif val in D1:
                D1.remove(val)
                checkforhit = True
            else:
                checkforhit = False

            if checkforhit == True:          
                match val:
                    case "00":
                        buttonspressed1[0] = "1"
                        button_list1[0] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        hit("1")
                        player1canvas.after(2000, lambda: player1canvas.place_forget())
                        player1canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(2,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
                  
                    case "10":
                        buttonspressed1[1] = "1"
                        button_list1[1] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        hit("1")
                        player1canvas.after(2000, lambda: player1canvas.place_forget())
                        player1canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(2,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
                  
                    case "20":
                        buttonspressed1[2] = "1"
                        button_list1[2] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        hit("1")
                        player1canvas.after(2000, lambda: player1canvas.place_forget())
                        player1canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(2,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
                    case _:
                        print("error1")
            else:
                match val:
                    case "00":
                        buttonspressed1[0] = "1"
                        button_list1[0] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        miss("1")
                        player1canvas.after(2000, lambda: player1canvas.place_forget())
                        player1canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(2,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
                 
                    case "10":
                        buttonspressed1[1] = "1"
                        button_list1[1] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        miss("1")
                        player1canvas.after(2000, lambda: player1canvas.place_forget())
                        player1canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(2,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
             
                    case "20":
                        buttonspressed1[2] = "1"
                        button_list1[2] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        miss("1")
                        player1canvas.after(2000, lambda: player1canvas.place_forget())
                        player1canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(2,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
            
                    case _:
                        print("error1")
                        
        elif player == "2":
            if val in A2:
                A2.remove(val)
                checkforhit = True
            elif val in C2:
                C2.remove(val)
                checkforhit = True
            elif val in D2:
                D2.remove(val)
                checkforhit = True
            else:
                checkforhit = False

            if checkforhit == True:          
                match val:
                    case "00":
                        buttonspressed2[0]  = "1"
                        button_list2[0] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        hit("2")
                        player2canvas.after(2000, lambda: player2canvas.place_forget())
                        player2canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(1,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
                
                    case "10":
                        buttonspressed2[1]  = "1"
                        button_list2[1] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        hit("2")
                        player2canvas.after(2000, lambda: player2canvas.place_forget())
                        player2canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(1,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
          
                    case "20":
                        buttonspressed2[2]  = "1"
                        button_list2[2] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        hit("2")
                        player2canvas.after(2000, lambda: player2canvas.place_forget())
                        player2canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(1,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
                    case _:
                        print("error1")
            else:
                print("miss")
                match val:
                    case "00":
                        buttonspressed2[0]  = "1"
                        button_list2[0] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        miss("2")
                        player2canvas.after(2000, lambda: player2canvas.place_forget())
                        player2canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(1,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
    
                    case "10":
                        buttonspressed2[1]  = "1"
                        button_list2[1] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        miss("2")
                        player2canvas.after(2000, lambda: player2canvas.place_forget())
                        player2canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(1,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
           
                    case "20":
                        buttonspressed2[2]  = "1"
                        button_list2[2] = "EMPTY"
                        grid.destroy()
                        miss("2")
                        player2canvas.after(2000, lambda: player2canvas.place_forget())
                        player2canvas.after(500, lambda: startingting(1,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2))
                    case _:
                        print("error1")
          
            
    def player1grid(buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2):
        print("player1grid")
        player2canvas.place_forget()
        player1canvas.place(x=100.5,y=100.5)
    
        
        n = 37
        b = 25
        for r in range(0,3):
            print(r)
            if buttonspressed1[r] == "0":
                button = tk.Button(player1canvas,command = lambda: empty(),bg="#FFFFFF", activebackground = "#008000", relief = RAISED,width="6",height="1")
                button.place(x=b,y=n)
                if check1 == 0:
                    button_list1.append(button)
                b += 100
            else:
                b += 100

            n += 100

        check1 = 1
        print(button_list1)
        print(len(button_list1))
        print("start of if")
        if buttonspressed1[0] == "0":
            grid00 = button_list1[0]
            grid00['command'] = lambda: buttonpress("00","1",grid00,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2)
        if buttonspressed1[1] == "0":
            grid10 = button_list1[1]
            grid10['command'] = lambda: buttonpress("10","1",grid10,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2)
        if buttonspressed1[2] == "0":
            grid20 = button_list1[2]
            grid20['command'] = lambda: buttonpress("20","1",grid20,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2)
        print("end of function")
        
        
    def player2grid(buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2):
        print("player2grid")
        player1canvas.place_forget()
        player2canvas.place(x=100.5,y=100.5)
        
        n = 37
        b = 25
        for r in range(0,3):
            if buttonspressed2[r] == "0":
                button = tk.Button(player2canvas,command = lambda: empty(),bg="#FFFFFF", activebackground = "#008000", relief = RAISED,width="6",height="1")
                button.place(x=b,y=n)
                if check2 == 0:
                    button_list2.append(button)
                b += 100
            else:
                b += 100

            
        check2 = 1
        print("start of if")
        if button_list2[0] != "EMPTY":
            grid00 = button_list2[0]
            grid00['command'] = lambda: buttonpress("00","2",grid00,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2)
        if button_list2[1] != "EMPTY":
            grid10 = button_list2[1]
            grid10['command'] = lambda: buttonpress("10","2",grid10,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2)
        if button_list1[2] != "EMPTY":
            grid20 = button_list2[2]
            grid20['command'] = lambda: buttonpress("20","2",grid20,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2)

        print("end of function")

    def switch_player(current_player):
        current_player = 3 - current_player
    def empty():
        print("broken")
        
    def startingting(current_player,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2):
        player1ships = len(A1)
        player2ships = len(A2)
        print(player1ships)
        print(player2ships)
        
        if current_player == 1:
            print("player 1s go")
            player1grid(buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2)
        else:
            print("player 2s go")
            player2grid(buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2)
        
        if player2ships == 0:
            print("player1wins")
        elif player1ships == 0:
            print("player2wins")          
        else:
            print("current player before",current_player)
            switch_player(current_player)
            print("current player after",current_player)

    current_player = 1
    check1 = 0
    check2 = 0
    buttonspressed1 = ['0','0','0']
    buttonspressed2 = ['0','0','0']
    button_list1 = []
    button_list2 = []
    startingting(current_player,buttonspressed1,buttonspressed2,button_list1,button_list2,check1,check2)
    
        
game = tk.Tk()

game.attributes("-fullscreen",True)

maincanvas = tk.Canvas(game,bg="#FFFFFF",height=game.winfo_screenheight(),width=game.winfo_screenwidth())
maincanvas.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)



player1canvas = tk.Canvas(maincanvas,bg="#FFFFFF",height="600",width="600")
player1canvas.place(x=100.5,y=100.5)

player2canvas = tk.Canvas(maincanvas,bg="#990505",height="600",width="600")
player2canvas.place(x=100.5,y=100.5)

play()
game.mainloop()
```

there is an almost identical version of this called (player2grid) that is used to switch between each players go, the buttons are assigned (using the if statements) the correct function (buttonpress) on player 1 and 2s first go, but as soon as the game loops round to player 1s second go none of the if statements work and all the buttons are assigned the original function (empty) which just prints out "broken" that i used to test the code.

well, when the whole code is run and as i said, it gets to player 1s second go, the buttons do the function (empty) not (buttonpress) and i cant see why the list of if statements work on the first iteration but not the second. ive tried added elses but results in the same problem.
ive also tried not having any if statements in the problem there is that if the button at place [0] (in button_list1) has already been placed then there will be a str item stored there ('EMPTY') instead of a tkinter button so an error is produced.so i need a way to only edit the buttons functions if they have not already been placed and so will still be stored as a tkinter button in 'button_list1' in there respective place

Comment: Why don't you print out the content of `buttonpressed1` to see whether it has the values expected?

Comment: @acw1668 even if the value of one of the items in buttonpressed1 were incorrect, the if statements for all the other ones should still happen right. but when i test it none of the buttons work. ive also tried creating if statements using button_list1 but the same thing happens

Comment: @acw1668 if the first if-statement isnt true, the others should still happen correct?

Comment: It is hard to tell without a [mre].

Comment: At least post the function `buttonpress()` which I think has modified those arrays.

Comment: @acw1668 i edited the original post that has code that is reduced but creates the same problem and you should be able to see for yourself

Comment: Please, use [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so it would be easier for us to reproduce and solve your problem

Comment: compared to the original thats pretty minimal, i dont understand how im meant to make it more minimal but still produces the same problem

Comment: When `player1grid()` is executed, it creates new set of buttons (which execute `empty()` when clicked) in the first for loop and place them in the same locations. But in the later `if` checking, it overrides the `command` option of *the first set* of buttons.  That is why `empty()` will be executed in 2nd round.

Comment: Oh yes that makes sense. Thank you so much, I’ll let you know how I get on trying to fix that

Comment: Also I think those `.after(2000, ....)` should be removed inside `buttonpress()`.